# Inheritance in Java with generic elements

Tags: java, inheritance

I apologize if these empty values/variables are not generic elements, I am really not sure about terminology in Java.

We are given this code:

```
public class AbstrClass <T, S> {
  private T value1;
  protected S value2;

  protected AbstrClass (T value1, S value2) {
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
 }

  public T getValue1() {
    return value1;
 }

  public S getValue2() {
    return value2;
}

}

public class Impl extends AbstrClass<String, Double> {

  protected Integer value2;

  public Impl (String value1, int value2) {
    super("Ferdinand", (double) value2);
    this.value2 = value2 + value2;
}

  public void incrementValue2 (Integer value) {
    super.value2 += value;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Impl impl = new Impl("Horst", 21);
  System.out.println(impl.getValue1());
  System.out.println(impl.getValue2());
  impl.incrementValue2(42);
  System.out.println(impl.value2);
  System.out.println(impl.getValue2());
}
}
```

And then we are asked what the result was if we run the code / the `main` method and why.
I am not sure if my reasoning is correct:

1. Ferdinand -> b/c it executes a method it inherits from the base `AbstrClass`, and since there is already a value, it prints out that one.
2. 21.0 -> b/c it exectues a method  it inherits from `AbstrClass`, but there is no value in it, so it gives out the given value of 21, but as a double, since it is defined in `Impl` as a double value.
3. 42 -> this one I really don't get.
4. 63.0 -> again this exectues from `AbstrClass`, (see question 2), and we add the 42 from the increment method, which results in 63.

Is my reasoning correct, and why does the third `System.out.println` result in 42?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of `Impl` is written:

```
this.value2 = value2 + value2;
```

Meaning for given input of `21`, `value2` will have the value of `42`.
`impl.incrementValue2(42);` only affects the variable of the same name in the `super` class.

`System.out.println(impl.value2);` will print the value of the variable `value2` of `Impl` - which was set to `42` in the constructor.

Your overall reasoning is good while not 100% on point

1. it calls `getValue1` on the base class which prints `value1`. `value1` was set in the constructor of the parent class to whatever was passed in as first argument. The constructor of `Impl` ignores its first parameter and always passes `"Ferdinand"` so the super constructor
2. it calls `getValue2` on the base class which prints `value2` of the base class. The fact that `Impl` has a variable of the same name does not matter. Your reasoning for the `.0` is correct.
3. see the base part of the answer
4. Maybe specify a bit more precisely why the value of the `value2` in the super class changed`

Answer (score 2):

That confusion is caused by something called field hidding. When you have the same field name in multiple classes in the same inheritance hierarchy you have multiple distinct fields.

So there is a Impl.value2 and a AbstrClass.value, there is a difference if you call this.value2 or super.value2 in Impl.

```
System.out.println(((AbstrClass<String,Double>) impl).value2);
```

will print `63.0`

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. For the third output, calling `impl.value2` will get the `value2` declared in the implementation, not the one of the parent class. This is because unlike methods, member field access is not resolved polymorphically, instead it is **resolved at compile time**. In other words, the field access expression `o.x` will access the field `x` that belongs to the type used to declare `o` regardless of the actual type of `o` at runtime.

The `value2` in the subclass is said to *hide* the one in the parent class since it has the same name.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to this:

- methods can be overridden
- fields can not be overridden

ie `super.foo` will always refer to the field `foo`  in the superclass, even if you have a field of the same name in the subclass.